# How to submit a HTML form without redirecting?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs, react-router

I am writing a client-side rendering web application using `react` and `react-router` for routing. I have implemented a search with an `input` inside a `form` with `react-bootstrap`.

```
executeSearch(){
    ...
    window.location.href = '/#/search/' + formattedURL
}

let formSettings = {
  onSubmit:this.executeSearch.bind(this),
  id:"xnavbar-form"
}

const searchButton =
<Button
  onClick={this.executeSearch.bind(this)}>
  <Glyphicon glyph="search" />
</Button>

const searchInput =
<form>
  <Input
    type="text"
    ref="searchInput"
    buttonAfter={searchButton}
    placeholder="search"/>
</form>

... Jumping to the render function

<Navbar.Form
    {...formSettings}>
    {searchInput}
</Navbar.Form>
```

Executing a search in `Mozilla Firefox` works as expected: Hitting the enter key and clicking on the `searchButton` route me to a client-side rendered page `.../#/search/...`.

Executing the search in `Google Chrome` behave like this: Clicking the `searchButton` works like above (client side render), but hitting the enter key cause a server redirect `.../?#/search...`.

I figured out it is caused by the form's `submit` attribute, how can I modify it to render on the client?

I was thinking about listening to a keyboard ascii code (enter) for executing the search, but it seems a bit messy.

Comment: If you are only switching the hash (and not the page location and hash) try just changing [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) instead the `href`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I do need to change the route, since I'm using `react-router` as my "components loader", it's not just changing the hash.
And what is it to do with `ajax`? I don't want to send a request to the server...

Comment: Have you ever heard about AJAX or Google? And more duplicated answers bellow...

Comment: Have you ever heard about client side rendering?
AJAX has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop the default behaviour of a form submit by using `event.preventDefault()`.

This will prevent the browser from submitting your form and instead leave the "routing" logic to you to do what you want it to.

Just accept the event in your `executeSearch` function.

```
executeSearch(event){
    ...
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = '/#/search/' + formattedURL;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! Just a heads up this works on any event that the browser can generate and not just submitting of forms.

Comment: Yea sure I know, it just didn't come to my mind when looking for a solution